# PHP Array of Array Element's differences

Tags: php, arrays, math, iteration, subtraction

I have a PHP array which contains numbers in the following format:

```
$data = array(2,4,3,12,11,1,5);
```

Is there an easy way to obtain a second array showing the differences of these elements as T-1 (setting 0 for the first)?

The new array would look like:

```
$data = array(0,2,-1,9,-1,-10,4)
```

Comment: What you have tried for it??

Comment: You can use `array_walk` to iterate through with a callback and pass the original array as the "userdata" third parameter so you can do the calculation. Give it a try and see what you come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this iterative subtraction process, the [minuend](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minuend) is each value in the array.
The [suptrahend](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subtrahend) is the previous value (or when no previous value, the first value in the array).  Because the first element's value and its suptrahend are always equal, the first value in the result is always zero.

All methods below will use the input array: `$data = array(2,4,3,12,11,1,5);`

When accessing the first element to declare the initial suptrahend, I used `current($data)` even though `$data[0]` would work, avoids a function call, and requires fewer characters.  This is to make my method more robust and suitable for processing arrays which do not begin with index `0`.

Here is the [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) version:

```
array_walk($data,function(&$v,$k)use($data){$v-=($k==0?$v:$data[$k-1]);});
var_export($data);
// $result=[0,2,-1,9,-1,-10,4]
```

The `array_walk()` method can be considered the best option because it doesn't create a `$result` array, nor does it need to declare a `$last` variable to preserve the previously iterated element's value.  Just be aware that you cannot squeeze the `array_walk()` line inside of `var_export()` -- this will return `true`.

This is the [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) version:

```
foreach($data as $k=>$v){
    $result[]=$v-($k==0?$v:$data[$k-1]);
}
var_export($result);
// $result=[0,2,-1,9,-1,-10,4]
```

`array_reduce()` allows the declaration of an initial suptrahend via the 3rd function parameter.  Here is the [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) version:

```
array_reduce($data,function($v1,$v2)use(&$result,&$last){$result[]=$v2-(is_null($v1)?$last:$v1); $last=$v2;},current($data));
var_export($result);
// $result=[0,2,-1,9,-1,-10,4]
```

Here is the [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) version:

```
$last=current($data);
array_map(function($v)use(&$result,&$last){$result[]=$v-$last; $last=$v;},$data);
var_export($result);
// $result=[0,2,-1,9,-1,-10,4]

// OR
// array_map(function($v,$k)use(&$result,$data){$result[]=$v-($k==0?$v:$data[$k-1]);},$data,array_keys($data));
// var_export($result);
// $result=[0,2,-1,9,-1,-10,4]
```

Here is the [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) version:

```
$last=current($data);
array_filter($data,function($v)use(&$last,&$result){$result[]=$v-$last; $last=$v;});
// $result=[0,2,-1,9,-1,-10,4]

// OR
// array_filter($data,function($v,$k)use(&$result,$data){$result[]=$v-($k==0?$v:$data[$k-1]);},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
// var_export($result);
// $result=[0,2,-1,9,-1,-10,4]
```

Comment: Thank you. The foreach() version works great. The array_walk() version seems to work but the first value of the original array stays the same instead of being set to 0.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da93d0d047a7679f61fcfcff7142c002ca8cc85e

Comment: @r1pster I have refined my answer since you accepted.  Please review the method options and select the one that you prefer for your project.  I recommend `array_walk()`.